# What's the best way to manage billing periods for multiple concurrent subscriptions with different prices?

Tags: architecture, subscription, saas, recurring-billing, system-design

There is a SAAS with an ability to have multiple paid subscriptions on different channels. Users are charged via recurring billings with float value.

```
Channel A cost = $10/month
Channel B cost = $15/month
```

E.g. a user makes a subscription to the channel A on January 1st, they are charged is on February 1st ($10). Then the user subscribes to the channel B on January 17th and the next bill is scheduled on February 17th.

One of the obvious solutions I've found is to suggest that the user pay the required part of the B subscription plus a main monthly price of $15.

```
required_extra_amount = (30 - 17) * $15 / 30
```

So the billing periods will be synchronised with a common billing date on the 1st day of each month. The price will be $25.

What's the best way to charge a user the least number of times?
I would be very grateful for any link on the subject.

Comment: Are you offering a multi-tenant SaaS application that you have built, and you want to figure out how to charge users based on their activity on your system, or, do you want to pass on the SaaS charges that you get, on to your users?  Or something else?

Comment: I've built a SAAS application where each customer can subscribe on multiple content channels at once and the total bill is the sum of prices. All the logic (subscription/charging) is implemented by me, so I'm flexible to any move. The core question is how to sync billing periods in the best way. In an ideal case, the user should be charged only once every month (it will be much simpler for understanding the total cost of the app usage). I'm sure that this challenge isn't unique and has an optimal solution, but my research on this subject didn't bring any valuable results.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bill on a fixed cycle, then charging users on a [pro-rata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_rata) basis is the obvious solution.  You code was on the right track - the only complication is that you seemed to assume a fixed 30 day month, which for a billing cycle might work (?).

I would probably do something like this:

```
UserCharge = (DaysToBeBilled / DaysInBillingPeriod) * FullPeriodRate
```

So if:

- DaysToBeBilled = 15
- DaysInBillingPeriod = 30
- FullPeriodRate = $10
- Month Charge = $5
- (30 / 15) * 10 = 5.

Furthermore:

- (31 / 5) * $15 = $2.42
- (31 / 17) * $15 = $8.22
- (31 / 30) * $15 = $14.51

DaysInBillingPeriod just needs to be set by some simple look-up for the number of days in the relevant month of the year, and, the algorithm would work with any length of billing period not just monthly.